# Convert excel/csv to below json format using python to trigger ansible jobs

Tags: python, json, excel, ansible

I am trying to do an automation, where i will be passing the information present in excel/csv to the automation script to do a `payload = requests.post(url,auth=(auth_user, auth_pass),headers=headers, data=json)` where each row will trigger a job in ansible.

My current excel/csv looks like(the format can choose as excel/csv whatever is easier as it is user input)

[image]

i want the json output like:

for first iteration:

```
json={"extra_vars" : " {\"dep_env\": \"CERT2\", \"ServerGroup\": \"Batch-server_group\", \"operation\": \"STATUS\"}"}
```

for second iteration:

```
json={"extra_vars" : " {\"dep_env\": \"CERT3\", \"ServerGroup\": \"Service-server_group\", \"operation\": \"START\"}"}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import json 
  
  
# Function to convert a CSV to JSON 
# Takes the file paths as arguments 
def make_json(csvFilePath): 
      
    # create a dictionary 
    data = {} 
      
    # Open a csv reader called DictReader 
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
          
        # Convert each row into a dictionary  
        # and add it to data
        json_arr = []
        for rows in csvReader: 
              
            # Assuming a column named 'ServerGroup' to 
            # be the primary key 
            key = rows['ServerGroup'] 
            data[key] = rows
            json_arr.append({"extra_vars" : str(json.dumps(data)) })
  
    
    # function to dump data 
    return json_arr
          
# Driver Code 
# Call the make_json function 
jsonres = make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```